# Python script can't execute SQL Select statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to execute a SQL SELECT statment from Microsoft SQL Server and write that data to an excel spreadsheet.

However, whenever I execute the Python script, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rrw\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 955, in fetchone
    row = dbapi_cursor.fetchone()
pyodbc.Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')     

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Astro\Python\AstroPy\WriteSQLData.py", line 91, in <module>
    for row in rs:
```

I can see from the error, that it doesn't like the line: `for row in rs` at the very end of the script. But I can't figure out why.

Is there anything I am missing?

Here is my script:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import csv
import configparser

# Get data from configuration ini file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('databaseConfig.ini')
destinationFile = config['destination']['fileName']

# Database Connection Code
connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=ASTROLAB;DATABASE=AstronomyMaps;UID=xyz;PWD=xyz"
connection_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

engine = create_engine(connection_url)

# Simple test query
qry = "SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM [AstronomyMaps].[dbo].[starMapA]"
with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(qry)
    
# Write query data to Excel spreadsheet 
with open(destinationFile, 'w', newline='') as f:
    a = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    a.writerow([x[0] for x in cursor.description])
    a.writerows(row)

    for row in rs:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you exit the context manager (`with` block) the statement has been executed but the rows haven't been retrieved yet. However, exiting the context manager also "terminates" the connection so `for row in rs:` throws an error when the ODBC driver tries to call `SQLFetch`.

You can avoid the error by using `.all()` to retrieve the rows while still in the `with` block:

```py
qry = "SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM [AstronomyMaps].[dbo].[starMapA]"
with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.exec_driver_sql(qry).all()
```